# How to set height and width of images in colorbox iframe?

Tags: jquery, iframe, colorbox

I am using colorbox iframe.

Images are opening inside `iframe`. Images are of different resolutions.

I have set the `scrolling: false` not to scroll if the image height and width increases.

But I can not see a full image, if it has the  size 3000X2000px .

I need to `resize` the image upto some height and width .

How can it be possible?

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Colorbox iframe resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377162/colorbox-iframe-resize)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.myImage').attr('style','height:xxx; width:xxxx;');`